# Can I boot Ubuntu from DVD

Tags: livedvd

Want to try running Ubuntu from DVD without installing - is it possible?  Trying to save some data from an old XP machine, and I am hoping to boot up with a Ubuntu disk that will allow me to go in grab files on machine, and then install XP

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is very much possible.

Just download the latest Ubuntu Image and create a Live DVD.

Now, boot from your DVD and select the `Try Ubuntu` Option.

[image]

You can find more details in the [Ubuntu site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if an ISO is bootable when written to a CD, it is also bootable when written to a DVD.

Actually, if you're trying to use Ubuntu 12.10 you must use a DVD because the ISO is too big to fit on a CD.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD

Comment: Actually it will fit on an 800MB CD which you can get but it will not fit on a standard 700MB CD

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to grab some files from that old pc, its easier with SystemRescueCD.

That is a Linux distro with only a few programs ( partitioning, memtest, file manager, antivirus, xfce desktop) and small memory usage. Perfect for old machines.

You can fint it [on this site](http://www.sysresccd.org/)

It's like a Swiss knife. Everybody should have it, on CD or USB, in case your PC crashes or don't boot anymore.