# Update/Upgrade ubuntu

Tags: 10.10, upgrade

I have ubuntu 10.10 maverik meerkat.  When trying to update using the onboard update manager generates message, "failed to download repository information, check internet connection". my internet connection works, (I can surf the web) I am trying to upgrade to the next version.

Comment: 10.10 has reached End of Life in Aprl 2012. Backup important files and install a supported release. Currently supported Ubuntu releases worth mentioning are 12.04 and 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

i would **back up my files first.**

then i would install the newest version off ubuntu.
[click here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265461/can-i-boot-ubuntu-from-a-dvd) for how to to that.  check the first post.

you can do this  by cd/dvd or usb i would use usb option because it can be faster most of the times.
here is how to create bootable usb on ubuntu [click here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

PS. sorry for the bad english writing.